# How can I use one variable in two components?

Tags: angular

This is a project built in Angular 6. I've got two classes, one and two. I want to use a variable in both classes. I've imported the class, but I'm not sure how to access the variable.

How do I use use "num:number = 2018" from one.component in two.component?

**one.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.css']
})
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {

  num:number = 2018;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  getNum() : number{
    return this.num;
  }

}
```

**two.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OneComponent } from '../one/one.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  templateUrl: './two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two.component.css']
})
export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {  }

}
```

Comment: Something to start with: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: This is good, but importing HEROES from './hero' makes a private variable, and therefore won't be able to synced between two classes. @R.Richards

Comment: If I were you I'd look into using redux-type architecture for keepings things in sync. If you keep connecting stuff from 1 component to another using things like input/output/viewchild/parenting you'll soon find yourself having some hard to read and maintain code. Try this tutorial to get a quick grip on what redux is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEcdQR-NoNA

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific in my link. Look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). Communication between components with a service may be what you need.

Comment: Are you trying to use `num` as a constant value, or will it have different values during execution of your application? If it is a constant value then just declare it as `static readonly`, and you can access it from anywhere in your application.

Comment: It'll have changing values @AndyKing

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you only have one root component. It means that all the other components are children of the same component, and picking 2 randoms components from your project they always have a common parent.

You can define the variable in the common parent, then give it as input to `one` and `two`.

Let's suppose that both, `one.component` and `two.component` are children of `app.component`. Then you have, in the `app.component` template:

```
<app-one [num]="number"></app-one>
<app-two [num]="number"></app-two>
```

and you need to define the variable in the `app.component` class (where else? Logically, there's no a reason why the variable should be in `one` rather than `two`)

What if `one` or `two` change the variable? Well, it depends..

If `number` is a string, a number or a boolean, it will be copied and `app-one` and `app-two` will work with their own local copy.

So you have three solution:

- Wrap your variable in an object. You'll pass the reference of any object as input. If the value of an object changes, the change detection mechanism will update all the tree
- Use `@Output()` to update the variable. Probably the variable will change as reaction to an event. When this event happens, also fire an EventEmitter.
- Use redux

Comment: I really like wrapping the variable in an object. Do i put the reference of the object in the app.component?